# What happens to android app that has firebase core library but the project deleted from the console

Tags: android, firebase

What happens to an app that has a firebase-core library, but the project is deleted from the firebase console.I have an app that has a firebase-core library in the play store, I am not using any other firebase feature like a database, storage, crashylitics etc.
For some reason, I want to delete firebase project and create a new firebase project from different id.My question is will the app crash as the app is already in play store.

Comment: if project have just a lib decency which using non of the feature of the Firebase   so it wouldn't affect your app, and deleted project can be retrieve  under 7 or some days . you can test your app and if get crashed then let it be the project same , upload new app with diff account